# How can I find out how much stack is left in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, stack-overflow

The JVM throws a StackOverflowException when the stack overflows.

That is fine, but not sufficient for my purposes.

I would like to know if I have *enough* stack to complete a certain computation. I.e., I want to know if my program has *nearly* but not yet run out of stack space.

Comment: You can create a `Throwable`, perform `fillInStackTrace` on it, and then do `getStackTrace` to find out what methods are currently in the stack, but it gives you no clue as to the space they occupy.  I don't think there's a way to do what you ask, other than to artificially blow the stack and see how close you were.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can query the vm for the current stack size.  But you can probably keep track yourself by keeping a total of the size of any local variables you are creating.

The stack size can be set by using -Xss option (ie: java -Xss4m)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this could at best be approached, as every stackframe as its own size.

Yet if you know the average frame size of the functions you're going to call, you could do that:

```
// assuming you'll need space for 4 references per frame on avg.
public static void checker(IntRef x1, Object x2, Object x3, Object x4) {
    x1.incr();
    checker(x1, x3, x4, x2);
}

class IntRef {
   public int frames = 0;
   void incr() { frames++; }
}

num = new IntRef();
try {
   checker(num, "a", "b", "c");
}
catch (StackOverFlowException ex) {
    // surprise :)
}
System.out.println("We can do approximately " ++ num.frames ++ " frames.");
```

Hope this helps.
Note that with usual stack sizes, this check will need almost no time.